# How to submit form in django at a scheduled time?

Tags: python, django

I have a typical form where users can put their values, submit the form and see the results in table:

```py
class ScanForm(form.ModelForm):
""" Creating a form for Scan results """
    value = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Value',
            'max': '500',
        }
    ))
    count = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Amount',
            'max': '400',
            }
    ))
    class Meta:
    """ Adding choice of interval and exclude unused fields """
        model = ScannedValue
        exclude = ('scan_date',)
        widgets = {
            'interval': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }),
        }
```

I'm rendering that form in my index.html file as usual.
And it's working normally when I put all the data and pushing "Submit" button.

But what I need is to **automatically submit this form** with filled values (let's say for 'value' = 5, 'count' = 10) at certain time, let's say 01:00pm every day. Then I need to parse all received data with function in my views after submitting the form and then save the results to database. What is the best and most right way to do this?

Here's function in views.py:

```py
def scans(request): 
    form = ScanForm(request.POST or None) 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            def fetch_scan(interval='1', amount=10, value=5): 
                # doing_some_stuff
else: 
form = ScanForm()
```

So I only want to launch function fetch_scan() automatically at certain time with my arguments every day.

Comment: use Python+Selenium which let you control web browser, fill form, click button, etc. Or use `requests` to send POST request with data without using web browser.. And then you can run it in any time using some sheduler or `cron` on Linux.

Comment: With requests I get an error "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)" and I don't want to turn off csrf token, because I have users who will also submit this form. Selenium is not good for my case because this project will be running on Linux server.

Comment: script has to work like web browser - first send GET to get page with form, cookies and `CSRF` and next send POST with data, cookies and `CSRF`. You can use `Session()` for cookies but you will have to find `CSRF` in form which you get with GET - you can use lxml/beautifulsoup to find it. And then you can use this value in POST.

Comment: Selenium can run brower  with option `--headless` and then it doesn't display window , it doesn't need GUI and it can run on server.

Comment: how is form filled? is there a special function in view to process data or you just want to save some values?

Comment: in `requests.post(url, headers, data)` you use `data={'login':"me", 'password':'secret'}` to send form.

Comment: This seems silly. Why use a form at all if you want to send information automatically?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe. How can I make this automatically?

Comment: @AmanGarg form has 2 inputs, after submitting form - the function in views doing a lot of work and parsing the results using values from those 2 inputs. If there is any other way to launch function from views with fixed values for those inputs - tell me how )

Comment: @furas Thank you, this is at least something to work with. But I want to know - is there some elegant ways to make similar tasks? Or the next step is Celery?

Comment: Well, as others have asked, where is the information coming from?

Comment: Your form as two simple values, why do you need to submit a form for that? why can't you just save them directly or run the values through your functions? why the form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I get values from user's form inputs and processing them with function in views.py, and saving them with the same function.
part of my function:
```python
def scans(request):

    form = ScanForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            def fetch_scan(interval='1', amount=10, value=5):
    else:
        form = ScanForm()
```

So I only want to launch function fetch_scan() automatically at certain time with my arguments every day.

Comment: @AmanGarg updated first post with additional information, please take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to submit forms for your use case. You need define the `fetch_scan` outside the view, and then convert it into a celery task. Then, it can be run as a periodic task.

```
@app.task()  # convert to celery task
def fetch_scan(interval='1', amount=10, value=5): 
       # doing_some_stuff

def scans(request): 
    form = ScanForm(request.POST or None) 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            fetch_scan()  # call the function
    else: 
      form = ScanForm()
```

Then you can just run the `fetch_scan` task everyday.

```
#settings.py

from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'daily-scan': {
        'task': 'path.to.fetch_scan',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=13),  #run daily at 1 pm
    },
}
```

[docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)